# Keep url while redirecting to a different page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect a particular set of Urls back to the index page of my site, but maintaining their url in the browser address bar. How would I go about to achieve this using `mod_rewrite` in a htaccess file?

The code currently used:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # Custom rewrite below
    RewriteRule ^references/(.*) / [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please note that this is a WP install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above rules you may already have:

```
RewriteEngine On

# for each of these "urls" do this
RewriteRule ^/?url_you_want_to_point_to_index / [L]
```

Assuming you have no query string parameters (the name/value pairs after a `?`), that should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks, doesn't seem to work though. FYI it's a WP install and I'm not sure how the system handles manual rewrites. I've updated the question and included the current code used.